# Intersection of solid of revolution and a line

Tags: vector-spaces, intersection-theory, solid-of-revolution

I want to find the Intersection Point and the normal vector of an intersection of a line and a solid of revolution.

I am currently programming some kind of lens simulator for my bachelor thesis, and i want to let the user define their own aspheric lenses by a function that gets rotated around the Y axis. To use the law of refraction I need to know the normal vector aswell as the intersection point of the line penetrating the solid of revolution.

I am thankful for every bit of help.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but thought I would answer as I've been working through this myself. [Yves Daoust's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1971393/680595) hinted the key insight for me, but I'll try provide a more concrete line of reasoning and the specifics that are needed to actually implement it.
$
\def\dot#1#2{#1 \cdot #2}
\def\v{\vec{v}}
\def\n{\vec{n}}
$

---

Define a solid of revolution by rotating a *non-negative* function, $f$, about the $x$-axis. In $\Bbb{R}^3$ the solid has an offset/position vector (herein assumed to be $\mathbf{0}$), and an orientation, defined by its axis of revolution, $\n$.

Define a line by the linear combination $L(t) = P + t\v$. In the general case it is assumed $\v$ is neither perpendicular nor parallel to $\n$ (see Special Cases below).

At an intuitive level, because the solid is invariant about $\n$, we can find the points of intersection where the perpendicular distance from the axis of rotation to $L$ is equal to $f$.

We can begin to formalise this by defining a function, $L_\perp(X)$, which maps to the point on $L$ whose offset from $X$ is perpendicular to $\n$, ie: $\dot{(L_\perp(X)-X)}{\n}=0$. This is given by:
$$
L_\perp(X)  = L\left( \frac{\dot{(X - P)}{\n}}{\dot{\v}{\n}} \right)
$$

Using $L_\perp$, we can define the perpendicular distance, $d$, by:
$$
d(x) = \Vert{L_\perp(x\n) - x\n}\Vert
$$

Expanding $d$ gives:
$$
d(x) = \sqrt{x^2(\dot{j}{j}) + 2x(\dot{j}{k}) + \dot{k}{k}}
$$

$$
j = \frac{\dot{\n}{\n}} {\dot{\v}{\n}}\v - \n ,
\qquad
k = P - \frac{\dot{P}{\n}} {\dot{\v}{\n}}\v
$$

(see Expansion Steps below)

The points of intersection can then be found by solving $f(x) = d(x)$, then substituting $x$ into $L_\perp(x\n)$.

---

**Special Cases**

**Perpendicular $\v$ and $\n$**

It's fairly obvious that $L_\perp$ is undefined in this case, so we need to use a completely different method.
Let $x = \dot{P}{\n}$.
Let $S$ be the sphere with centre displacement $x\n$ and radius $f(x)$.
The points of intersection can then be found by calculating the [line-sphere intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93sphere_intersection) of $L$ and $S$.

**Parallel $\v$ and $\n$**

The general case is still well-defined here, but extra care needs to be taken when solving $f(x) = d(x)$, as $d$ changes from a hyperbola to a constant value.
It's likely that a general-case closed-form solution will no longer be valid, due to the collapse of the quadratic term.
Instead, find $x$ by solving $f(x) = \sqrt{\dot{j}{j}}$.
The rest of the algorithm is unchanged.

---

**As a Hyperbola**

By completing the square, we can rewrite the equation for $d$ in the [canonical form of the conjugate hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Conjugate_hyperbola), augmented with an additional variable $c$ to encode displacement along $\n$.

$$\begin{align}
         \frac{y^2}{a^2} - \frac{(x-c)^2}{b^2} = 1
\implies \qquad y & = \sqrt{a^2 + \frac{a^2}{b^2}(x-c)^2} \\
d(x) & = \sqrt{
  \dot{k}{k} - \frac{(\dot{j}{k})^2}{\dot{j}{j}}
+ \dot{j}{j}\left( x + \frac{\dot{j}{k}}{\dot{j}{j}} \right)^2
} \\
\end{align}$$

While more complicated, converting into this form enables geometric reasoning about the shape of the hyperbola.
This might useful for when $f$ doesn't have a fully closed-form solution to $d$, depending on the geometry of $f$.

**Vertex**

The lowest point of the hyperbola, the vertex, lies at the point $(c, d(c))$.
This is given by:

$$
c = -\frac{\dot{j}{k}}{\dot{j}{j}}
, \qquad
d(c) = \sqrt{ \dot{k}{k} - \frac{(\dot{j}{k})^2}{\dot{j}{j}} }
$$

**Asymptotes**

The asymptotes of the hyperbola are the two lines given by:

$$
\pm\frac{a}{b}(x-c) = \pm(x-c)\sqrt{\dot{j}{j}}
$$

**Bounding Trapezium**

Using the vertex and asymptotes, it's simple to construct a fairly tight bounding surface which is useful for rejection testing.
For all $x$, $d$ satisfies the following:

$$\begin{align}
d(x) & \ge \sqrt{ \dot{k}{k} - \frac{(\dot{j}{k})^2}{\dot{j}{j}} } \\
d(x) & \gt (x-c)\sqrt{\dot{j}{j}} \\
d(x) & \gt (c-x)\sqrt{\dot{j}{j}} \\
\end{align}$$

If $f$ is convex, then its intersection points with this surface can serve as good starting estimates for an iterative solver.
In my implementation, I find the intersections with all three of these functions and $f$, and initialise my solver with the two which are closest (in the $x$-axis) to $f$'s inflection point.
In the case that $c$ is outside the domain of $f$, only one of the asymptotes can intersect $f$ and so the other is discarded.

---

**Expansion Steps of $d$**
$$\begin{align}
d(x) & = \left\Vert{L_\perp(x\n) - x\n}\right\Vert \ && \\
     & = \left\Vert{
         P 
       + \frac{ \dot{(x\n - P)}{\n} }{ \dot{\v}{\n} }\v
       - x\n
     }\right\Vert \ && \text{expand definitions of $L_\perp$ and $L$} \\
     & = \left\Vert{
         P 
       + \frac{ x(\dot{\n}{\n}) - \dot{P}{\n} }{ \dot{\v}{\n} }\v
       - x\n
     }\right\Vert \ && \text{expand dot product} \\
     & = \left\Vert{
           \left(P - \frac{ \dot{P}{\n} }{ \dot{\v}{\n} }\v \right)
       + x \left(\frac{ \dot{\n}{\n} }{ \dot{\v}{\n} }\v - \n \right)
     }\right\Vert \ && \text{group $x$ terms} \\
     & = \left\Vert{
       xj + k
     }\right\Vert \ && \text{create substitution variables $j$ and $k$} \\
     & = \sqrt{\dot{(xj + k)}{(xj + k)}} && \\
d(x) & = \sqrt{x^2(\dot{j}{j}) + 2x(\dot{j}{k}) + \dot{k}{k}} && \text{expand dot product and regroup terms} \\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you rotate the line around the symmetry axis, you get a surface which is a hyperboloid of one sheet.

[image]

The section of this hyperboloid by a plane through the axis is a hyperbola. So you need to find the intersection of the hyperbola with the profile curve of the lens.

[image]

The method to use depends on the type of the profile curve.